# Jenkinsfile error- java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'withMaven' found among steps

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am currently trying to implement pipeline in jenkins using jenkinsfile and i am executing a maven project on windows machine. I am creating a pipeline job in jenkins and i have checked in this file in my github repository and when i am running the job in jenkins , i am getting following error.

My jenkinsfile:

```
    pipeline {
        agent any
        stages {
            stage('Compile stage') {
                steps {
                    maven(maven : 'Maven_3.5.2'){
                        bat "mvn clean compile"
                }
            }
        }

             stage('testing stage') {
                 steps {
                    maven(maven : 'Maven_3.5.2'){
                        bat "mvn test"
                }
            }
        }

              stage('deployment stage') {
                  steps {
                    maven(maven : 'Maven_3.5.2'){
                        bat "mvn deploy"
                }
            }
        }

      }

    }
```

I am getting below error when i am running it through jenkins job-
Jenkins error:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'withMaven' found
>   among steps [archive, bat, build, catchError, checkout, deleteDir,
>   dir, dockerFingerprintFrom, dockerFingerprintRun, echo, emailext,
>   emailextrecipients, envVarsForTool, error, fileExists, getContext,
>   git, input, isUnix, library, libraryResource, load, mail, milestone,
>   node, parallel, powershell, properties, pwd, readFile, readTrusted,
>   resolveScm, retry, script, sh, sleep, stage, stash, step, svn,
>   timeout, timestamps, tm, tool, unarchive, unstash,
>   validateDeclarativePipeline, waitUntil, withContext, withCredentials,
>   withDockerContainer, withDockerRegistry, withDockerServer, withEnv,
>   wrap, writeFile, ws] or symbols [all, allOf, always, ant,
>   antFromApache, antOutcome, antTarget, any, anyOf, apiToken,
>   architecture, archiveArtifacts, artifactManager, authorizationMatrix,
>   batchFile, booleanParam, branch,

Any help?

Answer (score 20):

This means you don't have `withMaven` as an available DSL method. Most of the time this means you don't have a plugin installed. In this case, the Pipeline Maven Integration plugin is required. https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-maven/

Comment: I have installed the required plugin.How do i make use of it or just installing the plugin is enough?

Comment: my updated jenkinsfile has withMaven instead of maven but still the same error

Comment: If you just install it and use the appropriate syntax for the plugin, this should work. I haven't looked into the correct syntax, but withMaven is what that plugin provides, so changing to just `maven` you may have another problem now. Why did you change it?

Comment: It worked!Thank u Rob..i got it working using tools section. I have used tools {maven 'Maven_3.5.2'} immediately inside pipeline block

Comment: Great, you got it working. :)
Saw this conversation late !!

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
pipeline {

    agent any
    tools {
        maven 'Maven_3.5.2' 
    }
    stages {
        stage('Compile stage') {
            steps {
                bat "mvn clean compile" 
        }
    }

         stage('testing stage') {
             steps {
                bat "mvn test"
        }
    }

          stage('deployment stage') {
              steps {
                bat "mvn deploy"
        }
    }

  }

}
```

Reference: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/

Answer (score 3):

On top of Rob Hales' answer, it is called "Pipeline Maven Integration Plugin" in Jenkins ver. 2.73.3 or later

Answer (score 0):

You need to install all listed "pipeline" plugin and error no longer will be there.